# Change in Highcharts values of x-axis with event onClick()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i would like a suggest...

i have Time series charts (without event to zoom it), my data is this:

```
 data: [
            [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 14), 0.7695],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 21), 0.7574],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 28), 0.7480],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 5), 0.7685],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 12), 0.7744],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 19), 0.7652],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 26), 0.7609],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 2), 0.7526],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 9), 0.7542],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 16), 0.7540],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 23), 0.7487],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 7, 30), 0.7562],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 6), 0.7591],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 13), 0.7486],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 20), 0.7411],
            [Date.UTC(2013, 8, 27), 0.7393]
        ]
```

These are the starts of weeks.

i enabled scrollbar of x-axis in my chart and i set **range**:

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        range: 28 * (24 * 3600000)   // 4 weeks        
        },
```

in this way when the chart is ready, it show me last 4 week (and if i want to see other data, i will use the scrollbar)...
The problem is that the values of x-axis aren't my data :/

How i can to do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/k4ayprz4/

Besides i will insert a button under the chart with event onclick() that will reload the chart but with a **new range**

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        range: 3*(30 * (24 * 3600000))   // 3 months        
        },
```

the problem is that the values of x-axis in this case they should be names of months :/

Exist a way to do this ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** *I corrected the link jsfiddle and the array*

Comment: What do you mean with "values of x-axis aren't my data"? I can clearly see that the data you entered are the ones showing in the chart; unless I'm missing something? What do you mean with "they should be names of months"? Do you have an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: (See EDIT) Look into Jsfiddle, the latest array of my multidimensional array (the marker) it is September 27, but the last value shown on the x axis is 20 September. Here's what i mean with "values of x-axis are not my date."

Comment: In the highcharts there is no range option. You should call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) to set a range.

Comment: @SebastianBochan i tried setExtremes but it isn't a solution...  maybe i can to use categories and label ? do you understand what i would like to do ? my problem is that values of x-axis (values show in label) aren't same of markers in line chart

Comment: Do you mean that xAxis ticks are not in the same place as points ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan is possible to do it?

Comment: @SebastianBochan there is a problem if there are both **range** and **tickpositionier** ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan if there are range and tickpositioner and scrollbar for x axis is active, when i scroll, there aren't values on label :( http://jsfiddle.net/xwvs3cfw/